# Quarkus native build problem: No NameResolverProviders found via ServiceLoader

Tags: native, classloader, quarkus, graalvm

I have a well tested Quarkus microservice that I am trying to build in native mode. I am using latest Quarkus 3.2.2.Final. Problem is not present in JVM mode.

When I start the native microservice, during startup I get a WARNING:

```
"io.grpc.NameResolverRegistry","level":"WARNING","message":"No NameResolverProviders found via ServiceLoader, including for DNS. This is probably due to a broken build. If using ProGuard, check your configuration"
```

Of course, after that, communication with etcd fails with `cannot find a NameResolver for ip:///localhost:2379` and the application exits.

In JVM DEBUG mode I can see that a total of 7 resolvers are registered.

I tried explicitly registering classes for reflection, but it did not help.

```
@RegisterForReflection(targets={
    IPNameResolver.class,
    HttpNameResolver.class,
    HttpResolverProvider.class,
    IPResolverProvider.class,
    DnsSrvNameResolver.class,
    NameResolverProvider.class,
    LoadBalancerProvider.class,
    DnsNameResolverProvider.class,
    NameResolverRegistry.class
})
```

I suspect that this is not caused by classes not being properly registered, but rather by some native-related peculiarity in dynamic class loading.

Any suggestion of what to try next? I see no warnings during the build.

EDIT:

`Installed features: [cache, cdi, hibernate-validator, kafka-client, micrometer, mongodb-client, mongodb-panache, narayana-jta, quartz, reactive-routes, resteasy-reactive, resteasy-reactive-jackson, scheduler, security, security-properties-file, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-jwt, smallrye-reactive-messaging, smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka, vertx]`

I also see in native builder invocation line: `-H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature`.

EDIT 2, stacktrace:

```
2023-07-27 15:50:24,930 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile [prod]): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:111)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:71)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
    at com.y.z.responsedispatcher.ResponseDispatcher.main(ResponseDispatcher.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot find a NameResolver for ip:///localhost:2379
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.getNameResolver(ManagedChannelImpl.java:742)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.getNameResolver(ManagedChannelImpl.java:751)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.<init>(ManagedChannelImpl.java:631)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:631)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:297)
    at io.vertx.grpc.VertxChannelBuilder.build(VertxChannelBuilder.java:309)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.impl.ClientConnectionManager.getChannel(ClientConnectionManager.java:70)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.impl.ClientConnectionManager.newStub(ClientConnectionManager.java:102)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.impl.WatchImpl.<init>(WatchImpl.java:68)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.impl.ClientImpl.lambda$new$5(ClientImpl.java:53)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.support.MemorizingClientSupplier.get(MemorizingClientSupplier.java:37)
    at io.etcd.jetcd.impl.ClientImpl.getWatchClient(ClientImpl.java:85)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.core.EtcdClient.watchValues(EtcdClient.java:118)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.core.EtcdClient.watchValues(EtcdClient.java:112)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.core.EtcdClient_ClientProxy.watchValues(Unknown Source)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.z.services.zEtcdCache.init(zEtcdCache.java:41)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.z.services.zEtcdCache_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.z.services.zEtcdCache_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.z.services.zEtcdCache_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:113)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:37)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:34)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:21)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.z.services.zEtcdCache_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.z.services.zEtcdCache_ClientProxy.arc_contextualInstance(Unknown Source)
    at y.z.etcd.commons.z.services.zEtcdCache_Observer_Synthetic_7e505f92dfea7e2f74425f463632933f0b546710.notify(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notifyObservers(EventImpl.java:346)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:328)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.fireLifecycleEvent(ArcRecorder.java:155)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:106)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Which extensions are you using?

Comment: I added relevant log line from JVM build to the question.

Comment: Weird. Can you add the entire stacktace of the error?

Comment: Added stack trace.

Comment: I was not able to resolve this problem at all. I am internally using jetcd, and it has dependency on io.grpc:grpc-netty which I cannot make build in Quarkus native mode. 
I tried replacing grpc-netty with some other library. I tried quarkus-grpc, quarkus-netty, camel-quarkus-etcd3, none of it worked.
My conclusion is that it is not possible to use jetcd in Quarkus native build.